# Equation of a quadric surface on which this curve lies?

Tags: surfaces, parametric

I am currently learning about surfaces. So for the parametrized curve: 
$r=\langle t^2, 3t\cos(2t), 3t\sin(2t)\rangle,\quad t\ge 1$
how can I find a equation for the surface the curve lie? Also what kind of surface? Is it a paraboloid, hyperboloid of one sheet, hyperboloid of two sheets, etc. How can you tell which one it is?

Can someone please explain step by step this to me?

Comment: Some MathJax advice:

`<` and `>` mean "less than" and "greater than", and produce spacing correct for that meaning only; to make angle brackets, use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: @ZevChonoles Got it. Can you please help me here?

Comment: Start with the common trigonometric identity $\cos^2 2t + \sin^2 2t = 1$ and adapt it to get the first component in terms of the last two.  But this merely suggests a surface in which the curve lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that, by the usual trigonometric identity, 
$$y^2+z^2 = 9x$$

i.e. 
$$\dfrac{y^2}{3^2}+\dfrac{z^2}{3^2} - x = 0$$

Which would normally be a circular paraboloid extending in the $x$-direction. (Easily seen by noting that, for any fixed $x$, we have a circle of radius $3\sqrt x$ in the plane that is parallel to the $y,z$-plane at a distance $x$ from it.)

However, the parameterisation given forces exactly two values of $t$ for any fixed $x$ (namely $t=\pm \sqrt x$), where each yields exactly two points as opposed to a full circle for any fixed $x$. It follows that this curve is some kind of helical object of two strands.

Comment: So how can you tell what shape this is without graphing

Comment: Instead of circle, wouldn't it be more meaningful to say ellipse?

Comment: @rebecca See the edit. You either find a way to graph it (usually not too difficult by considering cross sections corresponding to fixed values of $x, y$ or $z$), or you remember the normal forms and try to reduce to them via a change of axes (See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadric#Euclidean_plane_and_space)

Comment: I think the original problem is more complicated. Since for fixed x, you have fixed $\pm t$, then you only have two point from the parametrization $r(t)$. It is not what you observe in this paraboloid: you have a circle for fixed x.

Comment: @rebecca, to answer your second question - No. Because in this case, the cross sections ARE circular, not elliptic.

Comment: @Sisi, you are indeed correct. This should trace out a more spiral-like shape. I'll edit my post.